# Improve code to use optional switch parameter in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a Powershell function that wraps **Invoke-WebRequest**.
Depending on the value of parameter $verbose I want to use -Verbose or not.

The code I have wrote using an API does the work... but I feel there should be a better way with less lines of code. It feels wrong to have twice the line with the **Invoke-WebRequest**

So my question is: **Is there a best way in Powershell to deal with switch parameters?**

Here is the function:

```powershell
function Invoke-MarkLogicManagementAPI($server, $apiFolder, $adminCredentials, $HTTPmethod, $body, $verbose)
{
    $resp1HTTPCode= "Not set"
    try
    {
        $uri = "http://$($server):8002/manage/v2/$apiFolder"
        if ($verbose -eq $true)
        {
            $resp1 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Body $body -Method "$HTTPmethod" -Credential $adminCredentials -ContentType "application/json" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        }
        else
        {
            $resp1 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Body $body -Method "$HTTPmethod" -Credential $adminCredentials -ContentType "application/json" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
        $resp1HTTPCode = $resp1.StatusCode
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
        $resp1HTTPCode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__
    }

    return $resp1HTTPCode
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a boolean to a switch parameter. In your case:

```powershell
-Verbose:$verbose
```

example:

```powershell
function DoSomething
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()
    Write-Verbose "output"
}

DoSomething -verbose:$true # Does write output
DoSomething -verbose:$false # no output
```

Comment: @cad Be aware that specifying `-Verbose:$false` is not the same thing as omitting `-Verbose` switch.

Comment: @PetSerAl Off the top of my head I can't figure the implications.... can you elaborate or do you have a reference?

Comment: @Matt run this: `$VerbosePreference='Continue';Write-Verbose Test1;Write-Verbose Test2 -Verbose:$false`. `-Verbose:$false` explicitly disable verbose output, while omitting `-Verbose` means use default settings.

Answer (score 3):

Since your question involves Verbose using `[CmdletBinding()]` is an easy way to account for that variance. I wanted to introduce to you [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) as well which is a great way to pass a varying number of parameters to a cmdlet while not having to actually write out each command.

```psh
function Get-Bagels{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$Filter,
        [switch]$Recurse=$false,
        [switch]$FilesOnly 
    )

    $parameters = @{
        Filter = $filter
        Recurse = $recurse
    }

    If($filesonly){$parameters.File=$True}

    Get-ChildItem @parameters
}
```

A *really* simple example is done be creating a hashtable `$parameters` and adding the parameters we want to pass to `Get-ChildItem`.I show a couple ways of populating the table notably you can see that the file switch is conditionally added with a small `if`.

This way no matter what parameters are being used the cmdlet call is the same every time.

So the following function calls will work

```
Get-Bagels -Filter "*.txt"
Get-Bagels -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse
Get-Bagels -Filter "*.txt" -FilesOnly
Get-Bagels -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse:$False -FilesOnly
```